# How to check filename and directory where constant variable is defined

Tags: php, global-variables, constants

I need to change my defined constant but ,I couldn't find where i've defined it  i.e.

```
<?php 
  define("var_name","somevalue");
?>
```

Is it possible in php to get where this constant is defined ??

Comment: use `runkit_constant_redefine`.

Comment: @FrayneKonok If i redefine it . It will reflect only on that page what about others ??

Comment: you don't know about the previous one, so you need to do it in every page, Or search it and replace it.

Comment: Try defining in the very first line of your script - you should then get a warning when the existing code tries to define it again, including the file and line number

Answer (score 0):

Using `runkit_constant_redefine` you can re define your defined constant.

```
runkit_constant_redefine("var_name_new", "somevalue_new");
```

more about [function.runkit-constant-redefine.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php)

> Note: If you have the [`runkit extension`](http://php.net/manual/book.runkit.php) installed, you can use
>   `runkit_constant_redefine()`

Comment: I am using ubuntu but cant get what the error is it displays blank screen even after applying ini_set ('display_errors',1) so I think this might be the issue of runtime extension is not installed on mysystem